# How to change position of Mesh.CreateBox

Tags: c#, eyeshot

What is the way to set the Position (x, y, z) after create a mesh
on create

```
  var pb1 = Mesh.CreateBox(8000, 400, 300);
  pb1.Color = Color.FromArgb(255, (byte)rand.Next(255), (byte)rand.Next(255), (byte)rand.Next(255));
  pb1.ColorMethod = colorMethodType.byEntity;
  pb1.Translate(0, 0, 0);
```

so i want set to x=0, y=400, z=0

```
SelectedEntity.Translate(0, 400, 0)
```

dosent work it set always to another position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `model1.Entities.Regen()` to see the effect of your changes. After the `Translate()` call, the `Entity.RegenMode` changes to `regenType.RegenAndCompile` status. The `Model.Entities.Regen()` call loops over all items of the `Model.Entities` collection and resolves their status to `regenType.NotNeeded`. `regenType.NotNeeded` status means that what you see is the actual position of the entity.